# how to make server visible from internet

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, ip, isp, static-ip

I have ADSL router with Static IP from my Internet provider. I know that, if I connect my server to router it can be visible from internet (working webserver etc.), but how does clients getting page know that, request should be put to server (I assume, there are many other devices like PC's in that local network).

Comment: What router do you have?

Answer (score 2):

You use port forwarding on your router so that any traffic originated from the outside to your public address to a particular port number gets forwarded to the IP address of the server.

For a web server, you would forward ports 80 and 443 to your web server's IP address.

Comment: And then advertise the public address in DNS so that clients can find it

Comment: If i will use port forwarding, will it not break connection to normal stations on that port?

Comment: Normal stations should not be getting anything on ports 80 or 443. Those are well-known port numbers for web servers.